# Minecraft whit Forge makes the minecraft screen weird

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-forge

I have instaled forge and open my minecraft so see if it's working i select the Forge profile to make Forge work but then when i hit the play button the screen locks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCtuQ.png

Some Information:

I play minecraft 1.7.10

I have download th FORGE forge-1.7.10-10.13.0.1180-installer-win

My mods folder is empty

I have instaled the Java 7

And here is some of my last log:

```
[15:54:48] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Minecraft jar mods loaded successfully
[15:54:48] [Client thread/INFO] [FML/]: Searching C:\Users\tmn\AppData\Roaming\.minecraft\mods for mods
[15:54:48] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining file forge-1.7.10-10.13.0.1180.jar for potential mods
[15:54:48] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: The mod container forge-1.7.10-10.13.0.1180.jar appears to be missing an mcmod.info file
[15:54:48] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining file launchwrapper-1.9.jar for potential mods
[15:54:48] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: The mod container launchwrapper-1.9.jar appears to be missing an mcmod.info file
[15:54:48] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining file asm-all-4.1.jar for potential mods
[15:54:48] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: The mod container asm-all-4.1.jar appears to be missing an mcmod.info file
[15:54:49] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining file akka-actor_2.11-2.3.3.jar for potential mods
[15:54:49] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: The mod container akka-actor_2.11-2.3.3.jar appears to be missing an mcmod.info file
[15:54:49] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining file config-1.2.1.jar for potential mods
[15:54:49] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: The mod container config-1.2.1.jar appears to be missing an mcmod.info file
[15:54:49] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining file scala-actors-migration_2.11-1.1.0.jar for potential mods
[15:54:49] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: The mod container scala-actors-migration_2.11-1.1.0.jar appears to be missing an mcmod.info file
[15:54:49] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining file scala-compiler-2.11.1.jar for potential mods
[15:54:49] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: The mod container scala-compiler-2.11.1.jar appears to be missing an mcmod.info file
[15:54:49] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining file scala-continuations-library_2.11-1.0.2.jar for potential mods
[15:54:49] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: The mod container scala-continuations-library_2.11-1.0.2.jar appears to be missing an mcmod.info file
[15:54:49] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining file scala-continuations-plugin_2.11.1-1.0.2.jar for potential mods
[15:54:49] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: The mod container scala-continuations-plugin_2.11.1-1.0.2.jar appears to be missing an mcmod.info file
[15:54:49] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining file scala-library-2.11.1.jar for potential mods
[15:54:49] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: The mod container scala-library-2.11.1.jar appears to be missing an mcmod.info file
[15:54:50] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining file scala-parser-combinators_2.11-1.0.1.jar for potential mods
[15:54:50] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: The mod container scala-parser-combinators_2.11-1.0.1.jar appears to be missing an mcmod.info file
[15:54:50] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining file scala-reflect-2.11.1.jar for potential mods
[15:54:50] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: The mod container scala-reflect-2.11.1.jar appears to be missing an mcmod.info file
[15:54:50] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining file scala-swing_2.11-1.0.1.jar for potential mods
[15:54:50] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: The mod container scala-swing_2.11-1.0.1.jar appears to be missing an mcmod.info file
[15:54:50] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining file scala-xml_2.11-1.0.2.jar for potential mods
[15:54:50] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: The mod container scala-xml_2.11-1.0.2.jar appears to be missing an mcmod.info file
[15:54:50] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining file jopt-simple-4.5.jar for potential mods
[15:54:50] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: The mod container jopt-simple-4.5.jar appears to be missing an mcmod.info file
[15:54:50] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining file lzma-0.0.1.jar for potential mods
[15:54:50] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: The mod container lzma-0.0.1.jar appears to be missing an mcmod.info file
[15:54:50] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining file realms-1.3.1.jar for potential mods
[15:54:50] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: The mod container realms-1.3.1.jar appears to be missing an mcmod.info file
[15:54:50] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining file commons-compress-1.8.1.jar for potential mods
[15:54:50] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: The mod container commons-compress-1.8.1.jar appears to be missing an mcmod.info file
[15:54:50] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining file httpclient-4.3.3.jar for potential mods
[15:54:50] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: The mod container httpclient-4.3.3.jar appears to be missing an mcmod.info file
[15:54:50] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining file commons-logging-1.1.3.jar for potential mods
[15:54:50] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: The mod container commons-logging-1.1.3.jar appears to be missing an mcmod.info file
[15:54:50] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining file httpcore-4.3.2.jar for potential mods
[15:54:50] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: The mod container httpcore-4.3.2.jar appears to be missing an mcmod.info file
[15:54:50] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining file vecmath-1.3.1.jar for potential mods
[15:54:50] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: The mod container vecmath-1.3.1.jar appears to be missing an mcmod.info file
[15:54:50] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining file trove4j-3.0.3.jar for potential mods
[15:54:50] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: The mod container trove4j-3.0.3.jar appears to be missing an mcmod.info file
[15:54:50] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining file icu4j-core-mojang-51.2.jar for potential mods
[15:54:50] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: The mod container icu4j-core-mojang-51.2.jar appears to be missing an mcmod.info file
[15:54:50] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining file codecjorbis-20101023.jar for potential mods
[15:54:50] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: The mod container codecjorbis-20101023.jar appears to be missing an mcmod.info file
[15:54:50] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining file codecwav-20101023.jar for potential mods
[15:54:50] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: The mod container codecwav-20101023.jar appears to be missing an mcmod.info file
[15:54:50] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining file libraryjavasound-20101123.jar for potential mods
[15:54:50] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: The mod container libraryjavasound-20101123.jar appears to be missing an mcmod.info file
[15:54:50] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining file librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar for potential mods
[15:54:50] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: The mod container librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar appears to be missing an mcmod.info file
[15:54:50] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining file soundsystem-20120107.jar for potential mods
[15:54:50] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: The mod container soundsystem-20120107.jar appears to be missing an mcmod.info file
[15:54:50] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining file netty-all-4.0.10.Final.jar for potential mods
[15:54:50] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: The mod container netty-all-4.0.10.Final.jar appears to be missing an mcmod.info file
[15:54:51] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining file guava-16.0.jar for potential mods
[15:54:51] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: The mod container guava-16.0.jar appears to be missing an mcmod.info file
[15:54:51] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining file commons-lang3-3.2.1.jar for potential mods
[15:54:51] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: The mod container commons-lang3-3.2.1.jar appears to be missing an mcmod.info file
[15:54:51] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining file commons-io-2.4.jar for potential mods
[15:54:51] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: The mod container commons-io-2.4.jar appears to be missing an mcmod.info file
[15:54:51] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining file commons-codec-1.9.jar for potential mods
[15:54:51] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: The mod container commons-codec-1.9.jar appears to be missing an mcmod.info file
[15:54:51] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining file jinput-2.0.5.jar for potential mods
[15:54:51] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: The mod container jinput-2.0.5.jar appears to be missing an mcmod.info file
[15:54:51] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining file jutils-1.0.0.jar for potential mods
[15:54:51] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: The mod container jutils-1.0.0.jar appears to be missing an mcmod.info file
[15:54:51] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining file gson-2.2.4.jar for potential mods
[15:54:51] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: The mod container gson-2.2.4.jar appears to be missing an mcmod.info file
[15:54:51] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining file authlib-1.5.16.jar for potential mods
[15:54:51] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: The mod container authlib-1.5.16.jar appears to be missing an mcmod.info file
[15:54:51] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining file log4j-api-2.0-beta9.jar for potential mods
[15:54:51] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: The mod container log4j-api-2.0-beta9.jar appears to be missing an mcmod.info file
[15:54:51] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining file log4j-core-2.0-beta9.jar for potential mods
[15:54:51] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: The mod container log4j-core-2.0-beta9.jar appears to be missing an mcmod.info file
[15:54:51] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining file lwjgl-2.9.1.jar for potential mods
[15:54:51] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: The mod container lwjgl-2.9.1.jar appears to be missing an mcmod.info file
[15:54:51] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining file lwjgl_util-2.9.1.jar for potential mods
[15:54:51] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: The mod container lwjgl_util-2.9.1.jar appears to be missing an mcmod.info file
[15:54:51] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining file twitch-5.16.jar for potential mods
[15:54:51] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: The mod container twitch-5.16.jar appears to be missing an mcmod.info file
[15:54:51] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Examining file 1.7.10-Forge10.13.0.1180.jar for potential mods
[15:54:51] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: The mod container 1.7.10-Forge10.13.0.1180.jar appears to be missing an mcmod.info file
[15:54:52] [Client thread/INFO] [FML/]: Forge Mod Loader has identified 3 mods to load
[15:54:52] [Client thread/TRACE] [FML/]: Received a system property request ''
[15:54:52] [Client thread/TRACE] [FML/]: System property request managing the state of 0 mods
[15:54:52] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: After merging, found state information for 0 mods
[15:54:52] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Injecting found translation data for lang en_US in zip file forge-1.7.10-10.13.0.1180.jar at assets/fml/lang/en_US.lang into language system
[15:54:52] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Injecting found translation data for lang en_US in zip file forge-1.7.10-10.13.0.1180.jar at assets/forge/lang/en_US.lang into language system
[15:54:52] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Injecting found translation data for lang es_ES in zip file forge-1.7.10-10.13.0.1180.jar at assets/forge/lang/es_ES.lang into language system
[15:54:52] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Injecting found translation data for lang fr_FR in zip file forge-1.7.10-10.13.0.1180.jar at assets/forge/lang/fr_FR.lang into language system
[15:54:52] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Injecting found translation data for lang ru_RU in zip file forge-1.7.10-10.13.0.1180.jar at assets/forge/lang/ru_RU.lang into language system
[15:54:52] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Injecting found translation data for lang de_DE in zip file forge-1.7.10-10.13.0.1180.jar at assets/forge/lang/de_DE.lang into language system
[15:54:52] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Injecting found translation data for lang en_US in zip file forge-1.7.10-10.13.0.1180.jar at assets/fml/lang/en_US.lang into language system
[15:54:52] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Injecting found translation data for lang en_US in zip file forge-1.7.10-10.13.0.1180.jar at assets/forge/lang/en_US.lang into language system
[15:54:52] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Injecting found translation data for lang es_ES in zip file forge-1.7.10-10.13.0.1180.jar at assets/forge/lang/es_ES.lang into language system
[15:54:52] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Injecting found translation data for lang fr_FR in zip file forge-1.7.10-10.13.0.1180.jar at assets/forge/lang/fr_FR.lang into language system
[15:54:52] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Injecting found translation data for lang ru_RU in zip file forge-1.7.10-10.13.0.1180.jar at assets/forge/lang/ru_RU.lang into language system
[15:54:52] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Injecting found translation data for lang de_DE in zip file forge-1.7.10-10.13.0.1180.jar at assets/forge/lang/de_DE.lang into language system
[15:54:52] [Client thread/TRACE] [FML/]: Verifying mod requirements are satisfied
[15:54:52] [Client thread/TRACE] [FML/]: All mod requirements are satisfied
[15:54:52] [Client thread/TRACE] [FML/]: Sorting mods into an ordered list
[15:54:52] [Client thread/TRACE] [FML/]: Mod sorting completed successfully
[15:54:52] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Mod sorting data
[15:54:52] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: No user mods found to sort
[15:54:52] [Client thread/TRACE] [mcp/mcp]: Sending event FMLConstructionEvent to mod mcp
[15:54:52] [Client thread/TRACE] [mcp/mcp]: Sent event FMLConstructionEvent to mod mcp
[15:54:52] [Client thread/TRACE] [FML/FML]: Sending event FMLConstructionEvent to mod FML
[15:54:52] [Client thread/TRACE] [FML/FML]: Mod FML is using network checker : Invoking method checkModLists
[15:54:52] [Client thread/TRACE] [FML/FML]: Testing mod FML to verify it accepts its own version in a remote connection
[15:54:52] [Client thread/TRACE] [FML/FML]: The mod FML accepts its own version (7.10.18.1180)
[15:54:53] [Client thread/TRACE] [FML/FML]: Sent event FMLConstructionEvent to mod FML
[15:54:53] [Client thread/TRACE] [Forge/Forge]: Sending event FMLConstructionEvent to mod Forge
[15:54:53] [Client thread/TRACE] [FML/Forge]: Mod Forge is using network checker : No network checking performed
[15:54:53] [Client thread/TRACE] [FML/Forge]: Testing mod Forge to verify it accepts its own version in a remote connection
[15:54:53] [Client thread/TRACE] [FML/Forge]: The mod Forge accepts its own version (10.13.0.1180)
[15:54:53] [Client thread/TRACE] [Forge/Forge]: Sent event FMLConstructionEvent to mod Forge
[15:54:53] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Mod signature data
[15:54:53] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]:    mcp(Minecraft Coder Pack:9.05): minecraft.jar (NO VALID CERTIFICATE FOUND)
[15:54:53] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]:    FML(Forge Mod Loader:7.10.18.1180): forge-1.7.10-10.13.0.1180.jar (e3c3d50c7c986df74c645c0ac54639741c90a557)
[15:54:53] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]:    Forge(Minecraft Forge:10.13.0.1180): forge-1.7.10-10.13.0.1180.jar (NO VALID CERTIFICATE FOUND)
[15:54:53] [Client thread/DEBUG] [Forge Mod Loader/]: Mod Forge Mod Loader is missing a pack.mcmeta file, substituting a dummy one
[15:54:53] [Client thread/DEBUG] [Minecraft Forge/]: Mod Minecraft Forge is missing a pack.mcmeta file, substituting a dummy one
[15:54:53] [Client thread/INFO] [FML/]: Processing ObjectHolder annotations
[15:54:53] [Client thread/INFO] [FML/]: Found 341 ObjectHolder annotations
[15:54:53] [Client thread/TRACE] [mcp/mcp]: Sending event FMLPreInitializationEvent to mod mcp
[15:54:53] [Client thread/TRACE] [mcp/mcp]: Sent event FMLPreInitializationEvent to mod mcp
[15:54:53] [Client thread/TRACE] [FML/FML]: Sending event FMLPreInitializationEvent to mod FML
[15:54:53] [Client thread/TRACE] [FML/FML]: Sent event FMLPreInitializationEvent to mod FML
[15:54:53] [Client thread/TRACE] [Forge/Forge]: Sending event FMLPreInitializationEvent to mod Forge
[15:54:53] [Client thread/INFO] [FML/Forge]: Configured a dormant chunk cache size of 0
[15:54:53] [Client thread/TRACE] [Forge/Forge]: Sent event FMLPreInitializationEvent to mod Forge
[15:54:53] [Client thread/INFO] [FML/]: Applying holder lookups
[15:54:53] [Client thread/INFO] [FML/]: Holder lookups applied
[15:54:55] [Client thread/TRACE] [mcp/mcp]: Sending event FMLInitializationEvent to mod mcp
[15:54:55] [Client thread/TRACE] [mcp/mcp]: Sent event FMLInitializationEvent to mod mcp
[15:54:55] [Client thread/TRACE] [FML/FML]: Sending event FMLInitializationEvent to mod FML
[15:54:55] [Client thread/TRACE] [FML/FML]: Sent event FMLInitializationEvent to mod FML
[15:54:55] [Client thread/TRACE] [Forge/Forge]: Sending event FMLInitializationEvent to mod Forge
[15:54:55] [Client thread/TRACE] [Forge/Forge]: Sent event FMLInitializationEvent to mod Forge
[15:54:55] [Client thread/TRACE] [FML/]: Attempting to deliver 0 IMC messages to mod mcp
[15:54:55] [Client thread/TRACE] [mcp/mcp]: Sending event IMCEvent to mod mcp
[15:54:55] [Client thread/TRACE] [mcp/mcp]: Sent event IMCEvent to mod mcp
[15:54:55] [Client thread/TRACE] [FML/]: Attempting to deliver 0 IMC messages to mod FML
[15:54:55] [Client thread/TRACE] [FML/FML]: Sending event IMCEvent to mod FML
[15:54:55] [Client thread/TRACE] [FML/FML]: Sent event IMCEvent to mod FML
[15:54:55] [Client thread/TRACE] [FML/]: Attempting to deliver 0 IMC messages to mod Forge
[15:54:55] [Client thread/TRACE] [Forge/Forge]: Sending event IMCEvent to mod Forge
[15:54:55] [Client thread/TRACE] [Forge/Forge]: Sent event IMCEvent to mod Forge
[15:54:55] [Client thread/TRACE] [mcp/mcp]: Sending event FMLPostInitializationEvent to mod mcp
[15:54:55] [Client thread/TRACE] [mcp/mcp]: Sent event FMLPostInitializationEvent to mod mcp
[15:54:55] [Client thread/TRACE] [FML/FML]: Sending event FMLPostInitializationEvent to mod FML
[15:54:55] [Client thread/TRACE] [FML/FML]: Sent event FMLPostInitializationEvent to mod FML
[15:54:55] [Client thread/TRACE] [Forge/Forge]: Sending event FMLPostInitializationEvent to mod Forge
[15:54:55] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/Forge]: Runtime patching class net/minecraft/world/gen/feature/WorldGenSwamp (input size 2205), found 1 patch
[15:54:55] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/Forge]: Successfully applied runtime patches for net/minecraft/world/gen/feature/WorldGenSwamp (new size 3564)
[15:54:55] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/Forge]: Runtime patching class net/minecraft/world/biome/BiomeGenSwamp (input size 1749), found 1 patch
[15:54:55] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/Forge]: Successfully applied runtime patches for net/minecraft/world/biome/BiomeGenSwamp (new size 2854)
[15:54:55] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/Forge]: Runtime patching class net/minecraft/world/gen/feature/WorldGenTaiga1 (input size 1593), found 1 patch
[15:54:55] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/Forge]: Successfully applied runtime patches for net/minecraft/world/gen/feature/WorldGenTaiga1 (new size 2666)
[15:54:55] [Client thread/TRACE] [Forge/Forge]: Sent event FMLPostInitializationEvent to mod Forge
[15:54:55] [Client thread/TRACE] [mcp/mcp]: Sending event FMLLoadCompleteEvent to mod mcp
[15:54:55] [Client thread/TRACE] [mcp/mcp]: Sent event FMLLoadCompleteEvent to mod mcp
[15:54:55] [Client thread/TRACE] [FML/FML]: Sending event FMLLoadCompleteEvent to mod FML
[15:54:55] [Client thread/TRACE] [FML/FML]: Sent event FMLLoadCompleteEvent to mod FML
[15:54:55] [Client thread/TRACE] [Forge/Forge]: Sending event FMLLoadCompleteEvent to mod Forge
[15:54:55] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/Forge]: Forge RecipeSorter Baking:
[15:54:55] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/Forge]:   11: RecipeEntry("Before", UNKNOWN, )
[15:54:55] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/Forge]:   10: RecipeEntry("minecraft:shaped", SHAPED, net.minecraft.item.crafting.ShapedRecipes) Before: minecraft:shapeless
[15:54:55] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/Forge]:   9: RecipeEntry("minecraft:mapextending", SHAPED, net.minecraft.item.crafting.RecipesMapExtending) Before: minecraft:shapeless After: minecraft:shaped
[15:54:55] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/Forge]:   8: RecipeEntry("forge:shapedore", SHAPED, net.minecraftforge.oredict.ShapedOreRecipe) Before: minecraft:shapeless After: minecraft:shaped
[15:54:55] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/Forge]:   7: RecipeEntry("minecraft:shapeless", SHAPELESS, net.minecraft.item.crafting.ShapelessRecipes) After: minecraft:shaped
[15:54:55] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/Forge]:   6: RecipeEntry("forge:shapelessore", SHAPELESS, net.minecraftforge.oredict.ShapelessOreRecipe) After: minecraft:shapeless
[15:54:55] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/Forge]:   5: RecipeEntry("minecraft:armordyes", SHAPELESS, net.minecraft.item.crafting.RecipesArmorDyes) After: minecraft:shapeless
[15:54:55] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/Forge]:   4: RecipeEntry("minecraft:bookcloning", SHAPELESS, net.minecraft.item.crafting.RecipeBookCloning) After: minecraft:shapeless
[15:54:55] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/Forge]:   3: RecipeEntry("minecraft:mapcloning", SHAPELESS, net.minecraft.item.crafting.RecipesMapCloning) After: minecraft:shapeless
[15:54:55] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/Forge]:   2: RecipeEntry("minecraft:fireworks", SHAPELESS, net.minecraft.item.crafting.RecipeFireworks) After: minecraft:shapeless
[15:54:55] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/Forge]:   1: RecipeEntry("After", UNKNOWN, )
[15:54:55] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/Forge]: Sorting recipies
[15:54:55] [Client thread/TRACE] [Forge/Forge]: Sent event FMLLoadCompleteEvent to mod Forge
[15:54:55] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Freezing block and item id maps
[15:54:55] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Registry consistency check successful
[15:54:55] [Client thread/DEBUG] [FML/]: Registry consistency check successful
[15:54:55] [Client thread/INFO] [FML/]: Forge Mod Loader has successfully loaded 3 mods
[15:54:57] [Client thread/DEBUG] [Forge Mod Loader/]: Mod Forge Mod Loader is missing a pack.mcmeta file, substituting a dummy one
[15:54:57] [Client thread/DEBUG] [Minecraft Forge/]: Mod Minecraft Forge is missing a pack.mcmeta file, substituting a dummy one
```

Comment: why this question was given negative vote ?   there is possibility that few more people would be experiencing same problem. so isn't it helpful to them?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about technical support for a modded version of Minecraft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following argument to your startup. It can be done in the launcher settings under JVM arguments

`-Dforge.forceNoStencil=true`

Do take note that some mods might not work after running with this argument as they depends on stencils to render their items. One such example is PortalGun mod.

The bug appear to be caused by the update of LWJGL to v 2.9.1. It is fully discussed on the minecraft forge GitHub page linked below.

https://github.com/MinecraftForge/MinecraftForge/issues/1185